# DrawLine on calling a function

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

```cs
private void Form1_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point p1 = new Point (300, 300);
    Point p2 = new Point (120, 120);      

    DrawLine(p1, p2);            
}

private void DrawLine(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    g.DrawLine(blackPen, p1, p2);
}
```

If I execute this Code, nothing happens.

I don't want to use the `Form1_Paint` event because I can only call this by the Start!?

I want to draw a Line when I want and where I want and as many times as I want
e.g. I fill 2 `Textbox`es with Points and then I click a `Button` and it draws a line.

Comment: Then you're misunderstanding what paint achieves

Comment: What if you, say, *minimize* and then *restore* the form? Do you want to *redraw* the line?

Comment: I want to draw different lines each time I press a button.

Comment: Learn the difference between Immediate and Retained graphics modes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684178(v=vs.85).aspx WinForms uses an immediate mode, while you're trying to think of it in retained mode concepts.

Comment: You can paint when you _want_, but the form is going to paint itself when it _should_, erasing every line you've drawn. You should remember which lines to draw, or draw them to a bitmap - but you're going to have to perform the actual drawing in the `Paint` handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `FormPaint` or similar approach. There are *many reasons* for forms being repainting (and that's why `FormLoad` is a wrong place: if the form change its size, be maximized etc it'll be repainted and the line'll vanish). On the contrary `Paint` fires when form has been painted - the best place to do an additional painting:

```
  // What to paint: a line [m_FromPoint..m_ToPoint] 
  private Point m_FromPoint = new Point (300, 300);
  private Point m_ToPoint = new Point (120, 120); 

  // Painting itself: whenever form wants painting...
  private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    // ... draw an additional line
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, m_FromPoint, m_ToPoint);
  }

  // Change painting (on button1 click)
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // We want a different line...
    m_FromPoint = ... //TODO: put the right point here 
    m_ToPoint = ...   //TODO: put the right point here 

    // ...and we want it at once - force repainting
    Invalidate();
    Update(); 
  }
```

Comment: Now it draws a line when it loads the form and when i Press the button and minimize it
But not instant so it seems the "Update();" is not working

Comment: @Julian: I'm sorry for the errror: you have to add `Invalidate();` - the request to redraw the entire form as well. `Invalidate();` - the from wants reapinting; `Update();` - repaint it now

Comment: Thank you now it works :)
And if I don't want to draw a line on starting the form, I change the two Points to
private Point m_FromPoint = new Point (0, 0);
private Point m_ToPoint = new Point (0, 0);

Or is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: @Julian: IMHO using a *flag*: `bool m_ShouldPaint = false;` and `if (m_ShouldPaint)  e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, m_FromPoint, m_ToPoint);` is a cleaner implementation